# jQuery Show/Hide on Checkbox Not Working

Tags: jquery

This is driving me crazy and must be simple.  Basically, I've got a little jQuery function that shows/hides a DIV when it's checked/unchecked.  Works fine in FF and Chrome, but doesn't work in IE7.  When I check the box in IE7, nothing happens.

Any ideas?

jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //Hide div w/id extra
    $("#extra").css("display","none");
    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id additional_contacts
    $("#additional_contacts").click(function(){
        // If checked
        if ($("#additional_contacts").is(":checked"))
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra").css("display","block");
        }
        else
        {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#extra").css("display","none");
        }
    });

});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="additional_contacts" name="additional_contacts" type="checkbox" value="yes"> 

 <div id="extra">
    <table>
      <tr class="content">
       <td width="256"></td>
       <td width="196">Email Address:<br><br></td>
       <td width="340"><input type="text" name="Email5" size="40"><br><br></td>
       <td width="170"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried binding to the `change` event ?

Comment: I don't know if this will help with IE7 woes, but I would change your .css(...) calls to .hide() and .show(), and I would also change your .is(":checked") to .prop('checked')

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Using version 1.7.  Also, there is no other Javascript on the page.

Comment: I'm using IE8 in IE7 browser mode, and it works fine.

Comment: It appears to work here, even in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/YpHDg/. Perhaps there's other code breaking on the site, preventing this JS from running. Without the rest of the HTML/Javascript, I'm not sure how much more I can help. Also, jQuery comes with two methods that might help you out. Check out .show() and .hide(), instead of using .css("display", "none"). Good luck. :)

Comment: Or better yet, use `.toggle()` instead of `.show()` and `.hide()`.

Comment: I don't think toggle would help him much, because we don't know what is the initial state of the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may be its the pseudo selector `:checked` that is not recognized by the IE

try

```
if ($("#additional_contacts")[0].checked) //use of [0] will return the DOM element
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra").css("display","block");
        }
        else
        {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#extra").css("display","none");
        }
```

or

```
  if ($("#additional_contacts").attr('checked'))
            {
                //show the hidden div
                $("#extra").css("display","block");
            }
            else
            {
                //otherwise, hide it
                $("#extra").css("display","none");
            }
```

OR

you can use `change` and `toggle`

```
  $("#additional_contacts").change(function(){
       $("#extra").toggle();
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L22eF/

Comment: I've tried all these solutions.  For whatever reason, it's not working.  I had it at least somewhat operational before when I would use jQuery to target a CLASS of "extra".  I had applied that class to individual table rows and it sort of worked, but messed up my alignment. Now I can't even get that to work.  Not sure what exactly is going on -- very bizarre behavior.

Comment: I finally got this to work.  Seems like IE didn't like the positioning of some of my <form> tags.  Works now!

Comment: @ndisdabest, for the sake of us readers, please explain specifically what IE disliked about the <form> tags, how you debugged it, and what needed to change?

Comment: @smci Basically, it was just very strict about the order of my code.  For this particular project, we needed to use tables.  The <form> tag needed to appear BEFORE the <table> tag and the </form> tag needed to appear AFTER the </table> tag.  Obviously, this is good coding practice, but this was an older form that had poorly structured code. After cleaning it up and logically arranging elements to have better form, this worked OK.  So, for others, I'd just advise that your code follow a good, clean structure if you encounter an issue such as this.

Comment: Ok, you mean the nesting of <table> inside <form> was incorrect. You can detect this with a HTML validator like e.g. [http://validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would solve your ie7 problem but try this code as also @jbaby noted:
$(document).ready(function(){

```
    //Hide div w/id extra
   $("#extra").hide();
    // Add onclick handler to checkbox w/id additional_contacts
   $("#additional_contacts").click(function(){
        // If checked
        if ($(this).checked) //notice the use of this here - better jquery practice
        {
            //show the hidden div
            $("#extra").show();
        }
        else
        {
            //otherwise, hide it
            $("#extra").hide();
        }
  });
```

});

for being jQuery pure you could exchange .checked for .prop("checked",true)

also try using this meta tag in the code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"  content="IT=edge,chrome=IE7">
```

notice that adding the chrome=IE8 isn't really needed but if you encounter a user with ie7 or less that installed chorme frame it would use chrome advanced rendering engine instead of ie7

(by the way you could also prompt them to install google frame- but that is out of topic)

from my experience this hack solves a lot of mystery IE problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check for Java script errors. In case if you have used console.log the functionality is not working fine as expected. Hence remove the console property and give a try!